# Java JNA UCHAR and PUCHAR

Tags: java, c, winapi, jna

I'm looking to get a Java string to '*WlanHostedNetworkSetSecondaryKey*' and '*WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty*'. One wants a struct within a struct with a CHAR[] and the first one wants a PUCHAR. I tried using *String, char[], byte[] and Memory*, but they will keep producing me the same errors (Bad parameters or Bad profile something for the first). Any way maybe to debug more with JNA (probably not :()?
I also can't read anywhere the characterencoding which is used, except that it's not ANSI.. Any help would be great!

```
        * DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkSetSecondaryKey(
        __in        HANDLE hClientHandle,
        __in        DWORD dwKeyLength,
        __in        PUCHAR pucKeyData,
        __in        BOOL bIsPassPhrase,
        __in        BOOL bPersistent,
        __out_opt   PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON pFailReason,
        __reserved  PVOID pvReserved


     * DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty(
        __in        HANDLE hClientHandle,
        __in        WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE OpCode,
        __in        DWORD dwDataSize,
        __in        PVOID pvData,
        __out_opt   PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON pFailReason,
        __reserved  PVOID pvReserved
        );
```

For the most documentation on this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439496(v=VS.85).aspx

http://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html#pointers

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access

Following comment:

```
   String buffer = "test";
   ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buffer.length()); buf.put(buffer.getBytes()); 
   Pointer pucKeyData = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(buf);

   System.out.println(
           CLibrary.INSTANCE.WlanHostedNetworkSetSecondaryKey(handle.getValue(), 5, pucKeyData, 0, 0, reason, reserved));
```

Comment: `PUCHAR` is defined as a C macro `POINTER(u_byte)` which is  a C pointer, `unsigned byte *` that points to an unsigned byte array. But, if you use `byte[]` or `char[]`  in JNA Structure, JNA will complain, `Array fields must be initialized` for `byte[]` or `char[]` field. In your case, it defeats the purpose of having `dwKeyLength` to define the size of dynamic unsigned byte array `pucKeyData`. The right type for the pucKeyData is `Pointer`. But, you need to find a way to assign an array to this Pointer field for `pucKeyData` based on the size given by `pucKeyData`.

Comment: I tried with Memory.setString and then Memory.getPointer, but it will crash the JVM.

Comment: Memory.getPointer is apparently unnecessary, since Memory is a Pointer already. Fixed the crash, but still results in Bad parameters

Comment: You need to use `Pointer` to represent `PUCHAR`. To allocate direct buffer unto Pointer for pucKeyData, you need to do the following: `ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(dwKeyLengthSize); buf.put(buffer.getBytes()); pucKeyData = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(buf);`

Comment: I tried accordingly, but still get the bad parameter result. (return 87, reason 2)..

Comment: If you use JNA `DWORD` as a parameter type in a JNA method, you need to assign an integer value of 5 to a `DWORD` type like this: `new DWORD(5)`

Comment: Don't use the value zero(0) to represent a false value in a `BOOL` type. You can use Java `boolean` type to represent WIN32 `BOOL` type.

Comment: Bad parameter means one or more of the function parameters are of incorrect data types...maybe, we need to see how you translate C structures and C functions above into JNA Structures and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am rephrasing what I have commented so far (plus some corrections):

`UCHAR` is defined as a C macro `u_byte` which is an `unsigned byte`. But, in Java, we don't have an `unsigned byte` type, just a signed byte from the `byte` type. Don't worry, to get an `unsigned byte` in Java, we use this trick: `((int)mybyte & 0xFF)`

`PUCHAR` is defined as a C macro `POINTER(u_byte)` which is a C pointer, `unsigned byte *` that points to an unsigned byte array. The reason is to have a dynamic array.

But, if you use `byte[]` or `char[]` in JNA `Structure`, JNA will complain, `Array fields must be initialized` for *uninitialized* `byte[]` or `char[]` field. In your case, it defeats the purpose of having `dwKeyLength` field to define the size of dynamic unsigned byte array `pucKeyData`.

The right JNA type for the `pucKeyData` is `Pointer`. But, you need to find a way to assign an array to this `Pointer` field for `pucKeyData` field based on the size given by `dwKeyLength` length in **WlanHostedNetworkSetSecondaryKey** structure.

To assign an initialized unsigned byte array to a `Pointer`, we need to use direct `ByteBuffer`. Remember to release this direct buffer manually after use since it is no longer managed by Java GC...

```
String buffer = "1234567890";
DWORD dwKeyLength = new DWORD(buffer.length());
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(dwKeyLength.intValue()); 
buf.put(buffer.getBytes()); 
Pointer pucKeyData = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(buf);

System.out.println("pucKeyData data:" + pucKeyData.getString(0));

buf = null;
pucKeyData = null;
```

If you get bad parameters from JNA exception, it means one or more parameters of your JNA method are using incorrect data types.

JNA provides a few WinDef class types like `DWORD`. But a few WinDef types like `PUCHAR` are not included. But, to assign an integer value to a `DWORD` type and retrieve it back, you need to do like this:

```
DWORD dwKeyLength = new DWORD(5);
System.out.println("dwKeyLength integer value: " + dwKeyLength.intValue());
```

Note: this post is based on JNA platform version 3.3.0